# Vibrational spectroscopy energy spectrum

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, spectroscopy, vibrations

I have a question regarding vibrational spectroscopy. In vibrational spectroscopy we are describing the vibration of molecules with the Morse potential which gives us stationary wavefunctions that give us the probability amplitude for finding the whole atom at a certain distance away from the other atom. The energys corresponding to this wavefunctions are discrete and so the spectrum is also discrete. However if the molecule is classical vibrating it should be described by a superposition of eigenstates and hence the spectrum should be continuous. So where is the problem?

Comment: "if the molecule is classical vibrating" -- what does this mean? Everything is always moving quantum mechanically; "classical" motion is just an approximation to quantum mechanics that holds when there are a large number of particles.

Comment: @Andrew but do we not model the system classical with springs that gives us then e.g. symmetric stretching modes? Or is this just a useful picture and the molecules don‘t change their position because they are in stationary states?

Comment: Sometimes people use classical analogies to molecular motion to help build intuition. Sometimes people use classical analogies to justify a form for a Hamiltonian that is used in a quantum mechanical treatment of molecular motion. However the exact dynamics are always quantum mechanical. You only see classical behavior emerge when there are a lot of particles and quantum effects "decohere." If you are looking at vibrational lines in a spectrum, you are looking at a quantum property where a molecule is transitioning from one state to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However if the molecule is classical vibrating it should be described by a superposition of eigenstates and hence the spectrum should be continuous. So where is the problem?

Superposition of eigenstates is fine, but it does not imply absorption spectrum should be continuous. When you analyze interaction of external field with the Hamiltonian, it is always strong for resonant frequencies defined by difference between Hamiltonian eigenvalues, and much weaker for frequencies that are not close to any such resonant frequency. Superposition state only changes which resonant frequencies can be "seen" in that state, but it does not introduce continuous spectrum. For continuous spectrum, one needs to have continuous spectrum of the Hamiltonian.

Answer (score 2):

Why should the molecule be described by classical mechanics? Classical mechanics is an approximation of quantum mechanics that works well for larger objects, but not at the scale of molecules. And in quantum mechanics the energy values a bound system can have are discrete (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_level)